# React Motion - Adding a child to another component during an animation throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have the following (simplified) structure:

```
<DumbWrapperComponent>
  <Messages/>  (listens to MesagesStore)
  <OtherUI/>     (listens to UIStore)
</DumbWrapperComponent>
```

Messages and OtherUI have two distinct stores they're listening to, so they (should) render independently of each other. OtherUI has some draggable elements using ReactMotion for smooth animation and an 'Add Message' button which adds a message to Messages using Flux pattern. It all works fine except for a case when you click the 'Add Message' button quickly after dragging something so the animation is still running. I get "Error: Invariant Violation: Expected flush transaction's stored dirty-components length (1) to match dirty-components array length (2)". What's worse it doesn't happen every time but more like 1 out of 3 times given the above condition.

I'm going to check it more thoroughly and update if I find the solution but I thought I'd ask just as a sanity check - is this an expected and known behavior/limitation of React Motion?

I'm still using React Motion v0.2.7 if that matters.

Comment: Can you disable the button while the animation is active?

Comment: Ha, that would be a quick and dirty solution and as such not a very bad one - I could delay adding the message until the animation is finished, except with React Motion it seems to be hard to tell when animation ends, cause it's spring based and currently doesn't expose `onEnd` callback.